# get sgml allow regex for "example.xom/page/200/"

Tags: regex, python-2.7, scrapy, sgml, sgml-mode

I'm trying to get the regular expression for "*example.com/page/200/*".

Here's what I've done so far:

```
rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(
  allow=("//page/\d+",),
  restrict_xpaths=('xxxxx',)),
  callback="details", follow= True),
)
```

Could anyone of you give me a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra slash, and you need to use a raw string. And, since there is a single expression only, you don't need to pass a tuple to `allow`:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"/page/\d+", restrict_xpath=('xxxxx',)), 
              callback="details", follow= True),)
```